# Collecting pyHook Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am i Ubuntu OS and get this error when try install [this](https://github.com/YCSU/pyRec/blob/master/record.py) python script, in [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) which needs to install `pyHook` module but get this error:

[image]

```
Collecting pyHook

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyHook
```

in terminal also get this error:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash/t$ sudo python -m  pip install pyHook
[sudo] password for so: 
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/home/so/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyHook
```

My Ubuntu OS version is:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash/t$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyHook is not installable from PyPI, you need to get it from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/

Comment: I thinks this module is working only in windows and not in linux!

Comment: That seems to be the case yes. There are other libraries that will work on Linux such as [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) but you will need to adapt that specific script to work with it.